# Como obter todas as letras do alfabeto em Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Eu gostaria de obter todas as letras do alfabeto numa lista de string sem ter que escrever letra por letra.

`a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p",
 "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]`

Answer (score 3):

Com Elixir você tem uma maneira de representar caracteres por valores binários, por exemplo:

Digamos que eu queira representar o valor binário da letra: `a`

```
iex(0)> <<97>>
"a"
```

O binário varia para a representação do caracter em caixa alta:

```
iex(0)> <<65>>
"A"
```

Elixir oferece um sintax sugar para que as representações binárias não fiquem tão hard code. Você pode obter o mesmo efeito apenas colocando um `?` antes do caracter da qual deseja obter o código:

```
iex(0)> <<?a>>
"a"
iex(1)> <<?A>>
"A"
```

Com isso temos todo o ferramental que precisamos para fazer nossa lista de letras do alfabeto:

```
iex(0)> Enum.map(Enum.to_list(?a..?z), fn(n) -> <<n>> end)
```

Ou se por um acaso quisermos a letras em caixa alta:

```
Enum.map(Enum.to_list(?A..?Z), fn(n) -> <<n>> end)
```